# How much does an air data module cost?

Tags: avionics, sensors

Curious how much Air Data Module and Angle of attack sensor costs, such that is used on commercial airliners.

Comment: I don't know specifically what that one costs, but as a "civilian" they will be extremely difficult to buy. I work with a company that manufactures avionics and sensors like that, and some of those types of sensors exceed $50,000.

Comment: You can't really estimate the price because each commercial airliner has a different design and manufacturers have contracts with suppliers. Your best estimation is by looking at the cost as a spare part

Comment: Thank you. I'm not looking to purchase one. I'm looking into manufacturing them and trying to estimate the market.
 Commercial airliners have different designs, however Honeywell, for example, has a list of standard equipment. It is not custom made for each airplane.

https://aerospace.honeywell.com/en/products/navigation-and-sensors/air-data-modules

Alas they don't have an online store. For spare part I could only find used equipment.

Comment: @SlavkaStack Each airframer orders customizations particularly in software, outputs, wiring, and mounting, even though the base module is the same. If you're trying to make your own, Airbus and Boeing will never buy from you; they buy complete integrated suites from Honeywell, Rockwell and Thales. They also need 30+ years of availability and the possible liability if it malfunctions and a 300 person plane crashes. Your best bet is to look at the ones from [small prop planes](https://sarasotaavionics.com/avionics/adc-2000).

Comment: You don't have just a module receiving AOA on an airliner.  You have an Air Data Computer that performs numerous functions with AOA just one of many inputs. Pricing depends on who's buying.  An OEM purchasing ADCs in bulk might pay 100k per unit.  An airline or other 3rd party might pay 150-200k for the same unit as a spare.  For the vane, the spares price might be 30k, while the OEM pays 10-15k.  OEMs know they have a captive market with their airline customers and they know the costs are just passed on, so the price gouging is quite brazen.

Comment: @user71659 Yeah, I realize it is a difficult task, but I think I have a better idea for AoA than existing vane or Pitot based systems, so I'm going to try.

Comment: @JohnK thank you, that is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For airliners, a lot of money, in the tens of thousands or more. Thales Aerospace is one of the manufacturers of AOA's for transport and military aircraft -- the word "cheap" does not exist in their vocabulary and "inexpensive" is a matter of opinion. For GA aircraft they are significantly less expensive, about US\$2000 or less. For aircraft with other than standard airworthiness certificates (experimental, homebuilt, etc.) the cost falls well under US\$1000. Sometimes manufacturers don't call them AOA's, and instead refer to them as "Lift Reserve System." For a general idea of the cost of GA AOA systems, [check Aircraft Spruce and search for "AOA"](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/search/search.php).